# R subset dataframe following rule based on date

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, subset

I would like to restrict my dataframe `my_df` using the following rule: if a province have all dates either before or after 26/09 they should be eliminated, as in `desired_df`

```
my_df <- data.frame(Province=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4),
                    date=c("23/09", "24/09", "25/09", "26/09", "27/09", "18/09","21/09", "23/09", "26/09", "29/09", "02/10", "25/09", "26/09", "27/09"))

desired_df <- data.frame(Province=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4),
                    date=c("23/09", "24/09", "25/09", "26/09", "27/09", "25/09", "26/09", "27/09"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question states that *all* rows must be either before or after 9/26 for the group to be excluded, implying that any group which includes that date should be retained. Yet your example excludes group 2??

Anyway, using `data.table`, this produces your example output.

```
setDT(my_df)[
  , .SD[between(as.Date('26/09', '%d/%m'), min(as.Date(date, '%d/%m')), max(as.Date(date, '%d/%m')), incbounds = FALSE)]
  , by=.(Province)]
```

You should be aware that the other answer will only work in 2022.

Comment: Indeed, you are correct, the previous solution solved but needed to correct for 2022

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`

I arbitrarily mutate `date2` for filtering `date`.

```
my_df <- my_df %>% mutate(date2=as.Date(date,'%d/%m'))

my_df %>% group_by(Province) %>% 
  filter(min(date2) < as.Date('2022-09-26'),
         max(date2) > as.Date('2022-09-26')) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-date2)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 8 x 2
  Province date 
     <dbl> <chr>
1        1 23/09
2        1 24/09
3        1 25/09
4        1 26/09
5        1 27/09
6        4 25/09
7        4 26/09
8        4 27/09
```